# How to check if a string contains a word from another list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
    public List<Article> Search(string input)
    {
        var searchQuery = input.Split(' ').ToList();
        List<Article> articlesResult = db.Articles
            .Where(a => searchQuery.Any(s => a.Title.Contains(s)))
            .ToList();

        return articlesResult;
    }
```

Purpose of the query is to find all articles, whom title contain a word from the searchQuery, but EF fails to translate it. If i added AsEnumerable() before .Where, it works fine, but it pulls all articles from the db.

Comment: Basically you want a bunch of `Like` conditions or'ed together.  You'll likely have to generate the required Expression for that vs using lambdas

Comment: InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Article>
.Where(a => __searchQuery_0
.Any(s => a.Title.Contains(s)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

@GertArnold Using EF Core 3.1.0

Comment: @juharr Yes, i might try to write it as parameterized sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for a list of books where the title *contains* a word from a user-supplied list. How would you do that in one SQL statement? It's *possible* to do by creating a table with an arbitrary number of `UNION`s and join in to the source table, or an arbitrary number of `LIKE`s, but the SQL provider has not been programmed to do that.

If you don't limit yourself to Linq, there are other ways to accomplish this without doing in-memory operations:

- Create a temp table with your list and join to that in your SQL
- Use a stored procedure and a cursor
- Use an arbitrary number of `LIKE` clauses (e.g. title LIKE "%@word1%" OR title LIKE "%@word2%")

But there's not a way to create any of those with the built-in LINQ provider. I would note that none of those seem particularly performant at face-value. The only way to know which is fastest is to try all of them and measure the results with a varying number of words.

Comment: FYI. EF6 would allow this query because it executes an EXISTS in a UNION-ed set of strings in the generated SQL. It's just that EF core doesn't implement that pattern.